# How to get the name of the file itself

Tags: javascript

How to get the name of the file itself?
example i use tha code in bla.js and it will get the file name itself
and will echo bla.js
and how to split it?
Like if the file use [RE]xxx.js will true , and if just xxx.js will false
sorry for bad english

Comment: document.currentScript can have what you want under certain circumstances = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: can't you use `str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));` ?

Comment: how to use `str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with node.js, then the filename is stred in `__filename` variable.